# Base64 string and Image

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

When I use images database for my asp.net web application , i found two methods !
First method is using "Image" data type , second is convert image to base64 string and store in "byte" data type .

I want to know which method is better in process and why ?

Comment: I've never found a compelling argument as to why actually storing the images *in* the database is any better than storing them on the filesystem (they are *files*, after all), and storing the path in the DB. Sometimes I think people just like to make things complicated.

Comment: It's hard to say what's best without knowing what are you doing?

Comment: You may also find this link useful [Storing images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: @Jacob , I just upload image , save to db and show to page .

Comment: @JacobSeleznev Thanks for that link. I'm not surprised that it's been closed, but there is a lot of good information there.

Answer (score 1):

[`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) type is deprecated so is not an option. There is no `byte` type in SQL Server, there is a type called [`tinyint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) which is equivalent to a `byte` type but I'm pretty sure that's not what you're asking.

So here is your *actual* question, corrected of wrong terminology:

> When I use images database for my asp.net web application , i found two methods ! First method is using [`VARBINARY(max)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms188362.aspx) data type , second is convert image to base64 string and store in [`VARCHAR(max)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) data type.

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding adds significant size to binary data, it converts 3 octets into 4 octets, so it adds 33% overhead. That is real estate consumed in your storage (be it database or file).

*However* a web application will serve media files *overwhelmingly* as base64 encoded responses. Having the file already encoded in storage saves CPU on the web server as it can stream the storage content directly, w/o going through base64 encoding. Not that base64 encoding is expensive (is very cheap and very much cache friendly) *when done properly, using streaming semantics*.

So choose your poison: save binary content for smaller disk space used, or take the 33% size penalty for faster response write and less CPU on your web tier.

For an example of properly storing and serving media files from the database see [Download and Upload images from aSP.Net](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/)

As for the neverending discussion about the storage be database or file system, I point you toward [To BLOB or Not To BLOB: Large Object Storage in a Database or a Filesystem?](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64525/tr-2006-45.pdf) and its conclusion:

> The study indicates that if objects are larger than
>   one megabyte on average, NTFS has a clear advantage
>   over SQL Server. If the objects are under 256 
>   kilobytes, the database has a clear advantage. Inside 
>   this range, it depends on how write intensive the 
>   workload is.

This study doe snot consider the administrative problems of an out-of database storage (consistent backup-restore, failover) but those kind of problems are only discussed in v2 of products.